# secure "related-key" stream cipher

Tags: stream-cipher, related-keys

Consider a stream cipher $E(k)$ which takes a key $k$ to produce a pseudo random keystream.

It should have the property that you can easily generate a set of at least 3 different keys $\{k_m, k_0, k_1, \cdots\}$ such that the key stream generated by the master key $E(k_m)$ is the same as XOR-ing all key streams of the other keys $E(k_0) \oplus E(k_1) \oplus \cdots$

Is this property a security risk by itself, or could such a cipher be used to speed up an encryption scheme with nested encryption, like onion routing?

If it could be secure, are there already any ciphers with such a property?

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: I'm just curious

Comment: If you consider symmetric encryption schemes instead of just stream ciphers, you're looking for "key-homomorphic encryption". There has been some work on lattice-based fully key homomorphic encryption schemes (see [here](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2014/84410298/84410298.pdf)).

Comment: @Mark thank you, I'd accept your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider symmetric encryption schemes instead of just stream ciphers, you're looking for "key-homomorphic encryption". There has been some work on lattice-based fully key homomorphic encryption schemes (see [here](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2014/84410298/84410298.pdf)).